# How to install Python 3.11 in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, version

I've installed Jupyter Notebook from https://www.anaconda.com/products/distribution

Unfortunately, it's default version of python 3.9, but the latest version is 3.11.

How can I install the latest version or other versions for jupyter notebook?

I'm using PC Windows 10.

Comment: Why do you need the newest Python?  Are you using something from 3.11?  Jupyter is meant to abstract away alot of these types of issues.

Comment: Not especially, just thought it would be useful in the future should I stumble across a Python module that has compatibility issues with any apps I build. Also, I prefer using Jupyter IDE over other IDEs.

Answer (score 7):

You first need to have Python3.11 and pip installed on your machine.

Then simply install the ipykernel module for python 3.11 on your system and activate it for jupyter :

```
$ pip3.11 install ipykernel
$ python3.11 -m ipykernel install --user
```

Once it is installed, you can start a jupyter notebook and check you are running the correct version using the following code :

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks Raphael, much appreciated. I simply did the following in my own answer. Hopefully this helps anyone else :)

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 22.04 on Windows 10. Using Anaconda, after installing Anaconda, I did the following.

To enter the Anaconda environment in the Ubuntu terminal:

```
source ~/anaconda3/bin/activate root
```

Then created a new environment with python 3.11 version:

```
conda create --name env311 python=3.11
```

Enter into the new env311 environment:

```
conda activate env311
```

Then update :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip
```

Then check the pip3 is installed:

```
pip3 --version
python3.11 -m ipykernel install --user
pip3 install notebook
```

Lastly

```
jupyter notebook --port=8889 --no-browser
```

Copy one of the URLs into your preferred web browser e.g.

```
http://localhost:8887/?token=0fb2c3dae305c11111182c9ac4a0efe9510d1514191993f036
```

Now you can select Python 3.11

In a cell, type in `!python --version`

This will confirm it's python 3.11.

For Jupyter lab, do a simple install of `pip3 install jupyterlab`
Then enter `jupyter lab --port=8889 --no-browser`

Copy one of the URLs (localhost or 127.0.0.1:8889) and paste into your preferred web browser, e.g. Google Chrome.