# langchain: No module named 'langchain.document_loaders'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, langchain

First and foremost I'm using the latest of Python (`==3.11.2`) and the most recent version of langchain (`==0.0.128`).

Following the [latest docs on DirectoryLoader](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/indexes/document_loaders/examples/directory_loader.html), the following line should work:

`from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader`

Instead, I'm seeing the following error. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 14):

The *ModuleNotFoundError* typically occurs when Python cannot find the module you are trying to import.

Assuming that you have already installed *langchain* using pip or another package manager, the issue might be related to the way you are importing the module. Here are a few things you can try:

1. Make sure that langchain is installed and up-to-date by running

```
pip install --upgrade langchain
```

2. Check that the installation path of *langchain* is in your Python path. You can check this by running the following code:

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

The output should include the path to the directory where *langchain* is installed. If it does not, you can add the path using `sys.path.append('<path_to_langchain_installation>')`.

3. Double-check that you are importing *DirectoryLoader* from the correct package. In the latest version of *langchain*, *DirectoryLoader* is located in the *langchain.loaders* module, so you should use the following import statement:

```py
from langchain.loaders import DirectoryLoader
```

If you are still having trouble, you can try uninstalling and reinstalling *langchain* to make sure that the installation is not corrupted.

Comment: Thanks for the assist! Turns out I simply needed to update my ipynb kernel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75545398/1130817

Answer (score 5):

Turns out that the `ipynb` kernel was using Python 3.7 instead of Python 3.11, even though the 3.11 was the default install.

I was able to verify this by running

```
from platform import python_version
print(python_version())
```

And fixed via https://stackoverflow.com/a/75545398/1130817

Answer (score 1):

I am using Python 3.11.5 and I run into this issue with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'langchain.document_loaders'` after running `pip install 'langchain[all]'`, which appears to be installing langchain-0.0.39

If I then run `pip uninstall langchain`, followed by `pip install langchain`, it proceeds to install langchain-0.0.308 and suddenly my document loaders work again.

- Why does langchain 0.0.39 have document_loaders broken?
- Why does langchain[all] install a different version of langchain?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load onlt .txt files from directory you can use

```
loader = DirectoryLoader('./training', glob='**/*.txt')
```

where './training' will be path of directory containing .txt file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from langchain.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on how the proposed solution solves the problem and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

For me the cause was, I didn't add python path to my system environment.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).